# How to add numbers inside a variable?

Tags: python, list, variables, numbers, addition

Let's say that:

```
print var
8
10
2
>>>
```

How do I add the numbers inside the variables together?

Comment: what type is that variable? a list?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sum(var). What have you tried/read/studied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
sum(int(y) for y in var.split())
>> 20
```

Comment: if that helped you please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean sum the numbers in a list?

```
sum(var)
```

should do the trick

Comment: its not a list the only way i can get that output is: x = '8\n10\n2', try doing: type(var)